# Needing Log Pcap

Tags: pcap, ss7

I need a Pcap Log for the interface between MSC/VLR and HLR (C or D), or between SGSN and HLR (Gr) with MAP/TCAP/SCCP protocol stack.

How can find that? or Is there anyone to give me that Pcap log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find pcap files containing MAP/TCAP/SCCP protocols [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures) and [here](http://www.pcapr.net/browse?proto=gsm%20map)

Comment: Thank you very much, can you answer my new question in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567281/needing-log-pcap-for-map-open-req-and-map-open-delimiter-req-messages]?