# Needing Log pcap for MAP_OPEN_REQ and MAP_OPEN_DELIMITER_REQ messages

Tags: pcap, ss7

Similar the question I asked before in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525328/needing-log-pcap), I also need a Log pcap for MAP_OPEN_REQ and MAP_OPEN_DELIMITER_REQ messages.

As I found pcap files containing MAP/TCAP/SCCP protocols [enter link description here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures) and [enter link description here](http://www.pcapr.net/browse?proto=gsm%20map), but there is no log Pcap for MAP_OPEN_REQ there.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

You won't find MAP-OPEN and MAP-DELIMITER in the pcaps because they are not sent over the wire.

These are common services/primitives used between the MAP service-user and the MAP service-provider. See [3GPP 29.002](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1585#) - "7 General on MAP services" and "7.5 General rules for mapping of services onto TC".

Comment: Thanks for your responseI am going to implement a VLR for a 3G network. So, according to your response, it seems that it is enough to send "SEND AUTHENTICATION INFO REQUEST" message to HLR for retrieving Authentication vector for a user (and I do not need to run any additional procedure or send the MAP_OPEN_REQ message). It is worth noing that I have established an M3UA/SCTP connection to HLR.

Answer (score 0):

The inbound roamer IMSI is sent as a parameter in the MAP `send authentication info request` message from the VPLMN MSC/VLR to the HPLMN HLR as component portion of TCAP dialogue. Here TCAP is MAP provider to transfer MAP service user data to destination MAP service user which is the HLR. In order to send mentioned MAP operation and receive its response, you need to implement whole SS7 layers; TCAP, SCCP and M3UA. You can not send only MAP message without adding other SS7 layers to route your message to target HLR entity. I would propose using Sigtran Softstack solutions to address all issues at once.